# How to reload Google chart on ajax submit?

Tags: forms, ajax, charts

I have a simple Drupal form. I am using `hook_theme()` to draw a chart right under my form. I am using *Google chart API*. When the page loads first time, my chart appears with no problems. But when I submit my form I use `ajax_command_replace()` to replace my chart with another one (without page reload). The goal is to make it possible to send variables from my form right to my theme function and draw another chart according to them. The problem is when I push the submit button the old chart disappears (which is good) and the new chart doesn't appear (which is bad). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is already created on drupal.org for this and you can try  the code from the below mentioned url:
[Ajax load of chart](https://www.drupal.org/node/1613258)

Comment: Thank you! Patch works: https://www.drupal.org/node/1613258#comment-6953012